# No me reconoce sintaxis de vuetify

Tags: vue.js, template, vue3, vuetify

Despues de instalar vuetify con el comando 'yarn add vuetify' no me reconoce la sintaxis en el template, antes me pintaba de amarillo las etiquetas, ahora ya no, es decir que no me aplica los estilos de vuetify, parece como si no estuviera instalado, probé desinstalar e instalar de nuevo pero no me funciona.
Estoy usando linux.
Por ejemplo el 'v-row' esta de rojo y las demas 'v-' tambien, les agradezco de antemano, adjunto codigo.

```
<v-row class="w-25">
  <v-col lass="mt-n2 mb-1">
    <input class="elevation-10 pa-1 bg-white text-black rounded-lg" v-model="nombre">
    <input v-model="idd" class="bg-white btn_id">
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Y esto es lo que tengo en mi package.json

```
{
  "name": "front",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "vue": "^3.2.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "vuetify": "^3.3.14"
  }
}
```

Comment: Estas usando algún IDE para desarrollar o algo? A mi me pasaba algo similar con Vue usando Visual Studio Code y era porque no tenia el entorno virtual activado en al IDE, luego de eso todos los errores y warnings se fueron.

Comment: Si estoy usando visual studio code, como activo el entorno virtual..?

Comment: en la consola me muestra: [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: v-col
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
  at <VueRoles> 
  at <App> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:41

Comment: visual studio code es un editor de texto plano... no reconoce nada, a menos que pongas las extensiones correspondientes. tenes las extensiones de vue correspondientes?

Comment: vs code a veces se pone terco... y tenes que reiniciarlo para que se de cuenta de ciertas cosas.. tambien fijate que extensiones te pide vuetify para que funcione bien...